# CASE when statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, case

I have a stored procedure in the works, however, I'm missing a few pieces of data when I run it. I know the reason why, but I'm having a hard time figure it out... this is my code:

```
INSERT INTO tempIntake (Pop, PlanID, PopFull, ApptDate, [1stAppt], Followup, Rn, UserID)
SELECT Pop, PlanID, PopFull, InterviewDate, 1 stAppt, Followup, rn, @UserID
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PlanID ORDER BY AddedDate ASC) AS rn
    FROM VInfo
    WHERE AddedDate IS NOT NULL
) t
WHERE rn = 1 AND interviewdate >= @fromDate AND interviewDate <= @toDate
```

So what I'm trying to do here is this....For some PLANID's I don't have an added date. Because I'm filtering by the AddedDate and in case is null - this data does not come up - even though I need it to be shown. In this case I'd like to make it a dummy date like '1/1/2016' this way, when the actually AddedDate becomes available in the table, it will be used instead of the dummy date.

Comment: this might sound weird, but can't you just....remove the `where AddedDate is not null`?

Comment: what I'm doing is even weirder. I have multiple values for some PlanId's ( addeddate = null and actual dates in some cases). When I partition by PlanID orderBy AddedDate ASC without the where addeddate is not null, i seem to pull up all the NULL values - when I actually need to pull the MIN date. I don't know why this is happening. All I need to do is basically specify when date is NULL then make it 1/1/2016 - and it will all be good. The data is not coming up for only 1 records out of thousands

Comment: well, then use `OVER(PARTITION BY PlanId ORDER BY ISNULL(AddedDate,GETDATE()))` and remove the `where AddedDate is not null `

Comment: post as answer and Ill accept. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AddedDate` can't be "bigger" then `GETDATE()`, you can use `ISNULL(AddedDate,GETDATE()))` and remove the `where AddedDate is not null` condition:

```
Insert into tempIntake(Pop, PlanID, PopFull, ApptDate, 1stAppt, Followup,   Rn, UserID)
    select 
        Pop, PlanID, PopFull, InterviewDate, 1stAppt, Followup, rn, @UserID 
    from 
        (Select 
             *,
             row_number() over (partition by PlanID order BY ISNULL(AddedDate,GETDATE())) as rn 
         from 
             VInfo) t
    where 
        rn = 1 
        and interviewdate >= @fromDate 
        and interviewDate <= @toDate
```

Comment: quick question - why don't I get the correct results if I partition by PlanID order by IsnuLL(addedDate,GetDate()) desc) as rn - i get all these null values - unless I include where addeddate is not null - theres something going on. The way you show it works for ASC, however when I partition by DESC - i get weird data

Comment: @FatBoySlim7 I mean, that's kind of obvious, since you are replacing `AddedDate` with `GETDATE()`, if you order them `DESC`  you'll get those `NULL`s first